# Why does my UI not update to reflect the data I have bound to it?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I've bound the visibility of some buttons to a bool, but when the bool changes, the button's visibility does not change. Why could this be?

The boolean is set up as such:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty editModeToggle = DependencyProperty.Register("editMode", typeof(bool), typeof(Window));
public bool EditMode
{
    get { return(bool)GetValue(editModeToggle); }
    set { SetValue(editModeToggle, value); }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the binding isn't at fault.

[Note: I have set up a Converter that works and the binding works. The visibility just doesn't change when I change from true to false or vice versa]

Binding:

```
<Button Content="Test" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=EditMode, Converter={StaticResource BooltoVisibilityConverter}/>
```

Comment: 1) Does the bool property notify change using INotifyPropertyChanged? 2) Do you use a converter to convert from bool to Visibility? 3) Do you see any binding errors in output window? 4) Have you tried putting a breakpoint on binding in xaml or setter in bool property?

Comment: @decyclone I haven't done the first... how would I do that?

Comment: Maybe "editMode" or is it just a typo?

Comment: The binding works when I first open the window, but if I change the value during runtime, the button doesn't change from visible to hidden

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the Converter methods and see when it is called and if it returns correct values or not

Comment: @Zabavsky Just realised what you meant, and after fixing it, it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency Property registration is not correct -

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty editModeToggle = 
DependencyProperty.Register("editMode", typeof(bool), typeof(Window));
```

It should be-

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty editModeToggle = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("EditMode", typeof(bool), typeof(Window));
```

Notice the spelling of property - `'E'` should be capital since its case sensitive and your property name is `EditMode` not `editMode`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to check when a binding does not work as expected:

1. Does the bool property notify change using
   INotifyPropertyChanged?
2. Do you use a converter to convert from
   bool to Visibility?
3. Do you see any binding errors in output
   window?
4. Have you tried putting a breakpoint on binding in xaml
   or setter in bool property?

As you have mentioned in your comment, you have not implemented *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface.

The need to implement the interface is whenever value of the property in ViewModel changes, there has be be a way for binding to know that. So, after implementing *INotifyPropertyChanged*, for each property, you raise the *PropertyChanged* event with the property name in it. That way, the binding knows that value of the property has changed.

There are lots of articles online. Here is one to get you started: [INotifyPropertyChanged and WPF](http://japikse.blogspot.in/2009/07/inotifypropertychanged-and-wpf.html)

Comment: Considering the bool property is part of a window class, how do you suggest I implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Ok, for Dependency Properties, you don't need that. Have you tried putting breakpoints directly on the binding and also in the *BooltoVisibilityConverter*'s methods?

Comment: It ended up just being a typo that I couldn't find... Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need point 1 from decyclone list since you are using a dependency property. I think that you should add Mode=TwoWay in binding if you don't have it, that will solve it.